# trouble charting with chartjs with data from MongoDB using flask and jquery

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I would like to create a line-chart with 2 lines showing 2 different datas. Shown below is the sample graph that i want to achieve

[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWJth.jpg)

shown below are the current collections that i have stored in MongoDB.
[trolley 1 collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXUwN.png)

[trolley 2 collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsoA1.png)

the code below is the flask app that i have created, '/' route is to display the page, '/data' route is where the chart retrieves the data from.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import pymongo
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client['mydb']

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('SmartTrolley.html')

@app.route("/data")
def data():
    line1 = db.trolley1
    line2 = db.trolley2

    results1 = line1.find()
    results2 = line2.find()

    return jsonify({'results': results1["temperature"]}), jsonify({'results': results2["temperature"]})

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=5000)
```

The code below is the my html where my chart is coded in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/SmartTrolley.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
        <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d')
        var getData = $.get('/data');
        getData.done(function(results) {
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['Tue 11','3am', '6am', '9am', '12pm', '3pm', '6pm', '9pm', 'Wed 12'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "trolley1",
                    fill: false,
                    data: results.results,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                }, {
                    label: "trolley2",
                    fill: false,
                    data: results.results,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                    align: 'start'
                },
                title: { 
                    display: 'true',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    text: 'Temperature recordings'
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            max: 30,
                            min: 12,
                            beginAtZero: false,
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    })
        </script>
    </div>
```

However when i run the flask app, the '/data' route shows the error "TypeError: index 'temperature' cannot be applied to Cursor instances". Also, the graph is not showing anything at all, including the labels of both x and y axis. Is anyone able to help with this, i would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns a cursor. If you are expecting a single record, you should use:

```
results1 = line1.find_one()
results2 = line2.find_one()
```